# Dart, using static variable with await/future

Tags: flutter, dart, static

I'm new to dart and wanted create a class that has a static variable but to be initialized with a value. No idea how to do it.

Something like this:

```
static Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
static String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate method initialize it And I am making nullable,

```dart
class Foo {
  static Directory? appDocDir;
  static String? appDocPath;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    final value = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    appDocDir = value;
    appDocPath = appDocDir?.path;
  }
}
```

Comment: The constructor will be called even if a static varibale called by refrence?

Comment: that's a good point it wont work, maybe we need factory constructor for this, let me test it

Comment: I just checked on the dartpad and the constroctor is not called by referencing a static variable.

Comment: yes, it wont call because static variable are class level

Comment: Any solutions of initializing it? since await needs to be called inside an async function

Comment: we can create separate method to initialize it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250897/discussion-between-kevin-woob-and-yeasin-sheikh).